# React widget based API async data fetch - Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

New at React and I am trying to build a widget based dashboard, but I can't get pass this error. No matter what I try and how I try go get the API data for a widget just added to dashboard by the user.

I wanted to make the API requests in a separate file "StatsService.js" and fetch data in "Layout.js" when the user adds a new widget to the dashboard and afterwards store the data using redux.

Here's the StatsService.js file:

```js
import  {useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';


async function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function WebserviceToken() {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();

    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    myHeaders.append("Origin", "*");
    
    var raw = JSON.stringify({
      "applicationToken": "--------",
      "customerUID": "--------",
      "privateKey": "--------"
    
    });

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw,
        redirect: 'follow'
      
      };

    const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const result = await fetch(`https://somewebsite.com/webapi/auth/webservicekey`, requestOptions)
            setResponse(result);
        })();
      }, []);

      if(response!==null){
        if(response.status=== 200){
            return await response.json();
        }else if(response.status === 429){
            console.log(response.headers["Retry-After"]);
            var RetryDelay = parseInt(response.headers["Retry-After"]) * 1000;
            console.log("Waitt number of miliseconds: "+RetryDelay)
            await timeout(RetryDelay);
            console.log("we waited")
            return await WebserviceToken();
    
        }else{
            console.log(response.status)
            console.log(response)
            alert("Something is very wrong fetching token! - check console")
        }
      }
}

export async function ApiCall({path,data}){
    let token ="";
    const [cookies, setCookie,removeCookie] = useCookies(['auth2']);


    if(typeof cookies.auth2 === "undefined"){
        (async () => {
            const result = await WebserviceToken();
            setCookie('auth2', result.token, { path: '/' });
        })();
    }


    token = cookies.auth2;

    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Origin", "*");
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);

    let querystring ="";
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        querystring+="&"+key+"="+value;
    }

    if (querystring){
        querystring = "?"+querystring.substring(1);
    }
      
    var raw = JSON.stringify(data);

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        redirect: 'follow'
      };

      
    const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
    const [responseJson, setResponseJson] = useState("");
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const result = await fetch(`https://somewebsite.com/webapi/${path}${querystring}`, requestOptions)
            setResponse(result);
        })();
      }, []);

    if(response!==null){
        if(response.status === 200){

            return await response.json();

        }else if(response.status === 429){
            var RetryDelay = parseInt(response.headers.get("Retry-After")) * 1000;

            console.log("Waitt number of miliseconds: "+RetryDelay)
            await timeout(RetryDelay);
            console.log("we waited")
            
            ApiCall(path, data);
        }else {
            console.log(response.status)
            console.log(response)
            alert("Something is very wrong! - check console")
        }
    }


    
}
```

And Layout.js

```js
import React, { useState,useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { Responsive as ResponsiveGrid, WidthProvider  } from "react-grid-layout";
import { withSize } from "react-sizeme";
import Widget from "./Widget";
import WidgetModal from "./WidgetModal"
import  CIcon  from '@coreui/icons-react';
import { cilApplications} from '@coreui/icons';
import widgetJson from './WidgetJSON'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import {CButton} from '@coreui/react'
import {ApiCall} from '../../services/StatsService'

const initialLayouts = {lg:[]};
const ResponsiveGridLayout = WidthProvider(ResponsiveGrid);
const Layout = ({ size: { width } }) =>{
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const leftPanelShow = useSelector((state) => state.leftPanelShow)
  const widgetData = useSelector((state) => state.widgetData)

  const [widgetModelVisible, setWidgetModelVisible] = useState(false);

  const [layouts, setLayouts] = useState(
    getFromLS("layouts") || initialLayouts
  );

  const [cols, setCols] = useState(12);
  const [breakpoints, setBreakpoints] = useState({ lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768, xs: 480, xxs: 0 });
  const [droppingItem, setDroppingItem] = useState({ i: "", h: 0, w: 0 });

  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState(null);

  const onLayoutChange = (_,allLayouts) => {
     setLayouts(allLayouts);
     onLayoutSave();
  };

  const onLayoutSave = () => {
      saveToLS("layouts", layouts);
      dispatch({ type: 'set', layouts: layouts });
  };

  const onRemoveItem = (itemId,event) => {
      setLayouts({
        lg:[...layouts.lg.filter(item=>item.i!==itemId)]
      });  

      onLayoutSave();

      return false;
  };

  const onAddItem = (item) => {

    var tempLayouts = {...layouts};
    var lg = {...item.gridLayout};
    if(typeof tempLayouts.lg === "undefined"){
      tempLayouts.lg = [];
    }

    let nextXPos = 0;
    let nextYPos = 0;
    let totalWH = {width:0,height:0,onlyHighestItemsInRow:0,highestItemInRow:0} 
    tempLayouts.lg.map(function(layout, i){
      totalWH.height += layout.h;
      totalWH.width += layout.w;
      if((totalWH.width % cols) === 0 || (tempLayouts.lg.length-1) === i){
        totalWH.onlyHighestItemsInRow += totalWH.highestItemInRow;
        totalWH.highestItemsInRow = 0;
      }else{
        if(layout.h > totalWH.highestItemInRow){
          totalWH.highestItemInRow = layout.h;
        }
      }
    })
    nextXPos = (totalWH.width) % cols;
    if(nextXPos!== 0 && nextXPos > (cols/2)){
      nextXPos = 0;
    }

    nextYPos =totalWH.onlyHighestItemsInRow;

    lg.i =item.id;
    lg.x = nextXPos;
    lg.y = nextYPos;

    tempLayouts.lg.push(lg)
    setLayouts(tempLayouts);
    onLayoutSave();
  };

  const ResetLayout = () => {
    localStorage.clear() 
    setLayouts(initialLayouts);
  }

  const onWidgetModalCloseClick = () => {
    setWidgetModelVisible(false)
  }

  const onBreakpointChange = (breakpoint, cols) =>{
    setCols(cols)
    setBreakpoints(breakpoints)
  }

  const onResize = (l, oldLayoutItem, layoutItem, placeholder) => {

    const heightDiff = layoutItem.h - oldLayoutItem.h;
      const widthDiff = layoutItem.w - oldLayoutItem.w;
      const changeCoef = oldLayoutItem.w / oldLayoutItem.h;
      if (Math.abs(heightDiff) < Math.abs(widthDiff)) {
        layoutItem.h = layoutItem.w / changeCoef;
        placeholder.h = layoutItem.w / changeCoef;
      } else {
        layoutItem.w = layoutItem.h * changeCoef;
        placeholder.w = layoutItem.h * changeCoef;
      }
  }

  const onDrop = async (layout, layoutItem, _event) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        var tempLayouts = {...layouts};
        setLayouts(tempLayouts);
        dispatch({ type: 'set', layouts: tempLayouts })
    }, 100);
  }

  const onDragStart = (item) => {
    setDroppingItem({i:item.id,h:item.gridLayout.h,w:item.gridLayout.w})
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    dispatch({ type: 'set', layouts: layouts })
    dispatch({ type: 'set', onDragStart: onDragStart })
    dispatch({ type: 'set', widgetData: widgetData })

  }, [dispatch]);
  

  useEffect(() => {

    layouts.lg.map((item,i) =>{
      var livedata = widgetData.filter(w =>w.id === item.i);
      if(livedata.length!==0){
        item.dataFromApi = livedata[0].data;
      }else{

        console.log(item);
        const wJson = widgetJson.filter(w=>w.id === item.i)[0]; 
        console.log(wJson);
        let data = null;

        (async () => {
          setApiData(await ApiCall({path:wJson.liveData.path,data:wJson.liveData.defaultValues}));
        })();

        data = apiData;
         
        var tempWidgetData = [...widgetData]

        console.log(tempWidgetData);

        tempWidgetData.push({id:item.id, data:data});
        dispatch({ type: 'set', widgetData: tempWidgetData })
      }

    })

  }, [layouts]);
  

  return (
    <>
    <div className="gridlayout d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
      <CButton color="primary" onClick={() =>  dispatch({ type: 'set', leftPanelShow: leftPanelShow?false:true })} className="me-md-2">
        <CIcon icon={cilApplications} className="me-2" /> Widget panel
      </CButton>
      <CButton color="secondary" onClick={ResetLayout}>
        Reset
      </CButton>
    </div>
      <ResponsiveGridLayout
        className="layout"
        layouts={layouts}
        autoSize={true}
        breakpoints={{ lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768, xs: 480, xxs: 0 }}
        cols={{ lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2 }}
        rowHeight={60}
        width={width}
        onLayoutChange={onLayoutChange}
        onBreakpointChange={onBreakpointChange}
        onResize={onResize}
        isDroppable={true}
        onDrop={onDrop}
        droppingItem={droppingItem}
        style={{minHeight: '500px'}}
      >
      {layouts.lg.map((item, i) => (
              <div
                key={item.i}
                className="card"
              >
                  <Widget key={item.i} onRemoveItem={onRemoveItem} chart={widgetJson.filter(w=>w.id === item.i)[0]} /> 

              </div>
            ))
          
     }
      </ResponsiveGridLayout>     
    </>
  );
}

export default withSize({ refreshMode: "debounce", refreshRate: 60 })(Layout);

function getFromLS(key) {
  let ls = {};
  if (global.localStorage) {
    try {
      ls = JSON.parse(global.localStorage.getItem("rgl-8")) || {};
    } catch (e) {}
  }
  return ls[key];
}

function saveToLS(key, value) {
  if (global.localStorage) {
    global.localStorage.setItem(
      "rgl-8",
      JSON.stringify({
        [key]: value
      })
    );
  }
}
```

The error is at `UseEffect`, where I loop through all the items in **layouts**, this is where I try to use either data stored with redux of fetching the API data, if data doesn't exist.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You are not allowed to use React hooks inside functions, that are _not_ react components or react hooks themselves. `WebserviceToken` is neither of those two, so react is rightly complaining. The same is true for `ApiCall`.

Comment: How to solve this? How can i fetch data from api when layouts changes?

Comment: Either you remove the call to react hooks from those 2 methods OR you convert them to react hooks.